# Disable automatic slide. Library android-menudrawer

Tags: android, libraries, slide

I'm using this library in my project:

android-ManuDrawer
https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

It works perfectly, the problem is my English is not very good, and I can not find a way to disable that every x seconds, it automatically slide.

I guess it will be a parameter scroller class, but can not understand the code correctly.

Need to disable the automatic slide

I appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the undesired effect? When does it happen? Can you show the code you use to work with this library?

EDIT:

The reason is on this method (https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/menudrawer/MenuDrawer.java) Line 58:

```
@Override
public void postOnAnimation(Runnable action) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        super.postOnAnimation(action);
    } else {
        postDelayed(action, ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }
}
```

I guess there should be a reason for that. In case the effect is undesired you can just avoid calling it commenting line 745, but there's should be a reason why it is there and why there was no option given to the user to get rid of it.

Comment: The unwanted effect is that every x seconds, the side menu automatically slides as a demonstration for the user.
This happens when the screen is not touched for 20 or 30 seconds.
The class where I think is the parameter is this: http://goo.gl/1JyUC

Answer (score 1):

Just don't call mMenuDrawer.peekDrawer()

Answer (score 0):

```
mMenuDrawer.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_NONE);
```